# why need to use spread operator when passing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the code:

```
const Info = (props) => (
    <div>
        <h1>Info</h1>
        <p>The info is: {props.info}</p>
    </div>
);

const withAdminWarning = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return (props) => (
        <div>
           <p>This is private info. Please don't share!</p>
           <WrappedComponent {...props}/>   // why need to use spread operator?
        </div>
    );
};

const AdminInfo = withAdminWarning(Info);

ReactDOM.render(<AdminInfo info="There are the details" />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

what I don't understand is, why it has to be :

```
 <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
```

and I can't pass an object as:

```
const temp = {info: "There are the details"}
<WrappedComponent temp/>
```

isn't that {...props} an object too?

Comment: `<WrappedComponent temp/>` is same as `<WrappedComponent temp={true}/>`, so if you want to pass an object write it like this: `<WrappedComponent temp={temp} />` or `<WrappedComponent temp={{a:1, b:2}} />` and check the linked answer for `{...props}` part, very well explained.

Comment: Short answer is it is simply to be able to pass all the `props` from current component to another component so you can easily access any of them without having to write them all out manually or even worry what their names are

Comment: `withAdminWarning` is a function that gets a `Component`, does something with it, and returns *another* component. But you want that component to still have the props. You could do this:
```javascript
<WrappedComponent prop1={props.prop1} prop2={props.prop2} propN={prop.propN} />
```
But also, you could use the `spread operator` syntax to achieve the same thing:
```javascript
<WrappedComponent {...props} />
```
By the way, this pattern is known as `High Order Components` and you can find all you need about this here: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use the spread operator, you can also do something like

```js
const temp = { info: "There are the details }
<WrappedElement temp={temp} />
```

You can later access it with `props.temp.info`

Comment: tried that, didn't work

Comment: @slowjams Sorry, my bad. I fixed it now